# Create email, based on Outlook template, from a Word menu

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

This is the code for other Word templates on the menu.

```vb
Private Sub "button name_Click()
    Unload ####Menu
End Sub
```

This is code I've seen to create an Outlook item from Word.

```vb
Sub CreateFromTemplate() 
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
     
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\statusrep.oft") 
    MyItem.Display 
End Sub 
     
Sub CreateTemplate() 
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
     
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    MyItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
    MyItem.To = "Dan Wilson" 
    MyItem.Display 
    MyItem.SaveAs "C:\statusrep.oft", OlSaveAsType.olTemplate 
End Sub
```

How do I combine these?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to automate Outlook from Word VBA. To start an Outlook Automation session, you can use either early or late binding. Late binding uses either the Visual Basic `GetObject` function or the `CreateObject` function to initialize Outlook. For example, the following code sets an object variable to the Outlook Application object, which is the highest-level object in the Outlook object model. All Automation code must first define an Outlook `Application` object to be able to access any other Outlook objects.

```
Dim objOL as Object 
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

To use early binding, you first need to set a reference to the Outlook object library. Use the `Reference` command on the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Tools menu to set a reference to Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library, where xx.x represents the version of Outlook that you are working with. You can then use the following syntax to start an Outlook session.

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application 
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
```

Most programming solutions interact with the data stored in Outlook. Outlook stores all of its information as items in folders. Folders are contained in one or more stores. After you set an object variable to the Outlook Application object, you will commonly set a `NameSpace` object to refer to MAPI, as shown in the following example.

```
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application 
Set objNS = objOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
```

Once you have set an object variable to reference the folder that contains the items you wish to work with, you use appropriate code to accomplish your task, as shown in the following example.

```
Sub CreateNewOutlookMail() 
    Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application 
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    ' Set the Application object 
    Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application 
    ' You can only use CreateItem for default items 
    Set NewMail = objOLApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    ' Display the new mail form so the user can fill it out 
    NewMail.Display 
End Sub
```

See [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) for more information.

Comment: Thank you!  I get a blank email to popup and I understand most of this now. How can i make it open a "oft" that we created instead of the blank email

Comment: i figured it out - thank you so very much